# How can I capitalize the letters of my domain name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Suppose my domain name is www.hello.com

How can I use jQuery/JavaScript to make the browser's URL bar look like "www.HELLO.com"?

Comment: I don't think that's how the internet is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change what gets displayed in the browser's URL bar. That is a basic security feature.

<strike>You could make your domain all upper case (and redirect the pages to that version).</strike> (That apparently does not work, see @Kristian's comment: Most browsers are not concerned about case, hence a redirect to HELLO.com would still appear as hello.com)

You could also display HELLO.com in the browser window's title bar (the HTML document title).

Comment: You could make your domain all upper case (and redirect the pages to that version). <<< how?

Comment: -1 Most browsers are not concerned about case, hence a redirect to `HELLO.com` would still appear as `hello.com`.

Comment: @kba, if you think so, could you plz answer my [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551517/capitalizing-a-domain-name-in-a-url-using-javascript)?